# What document.body is equal to with equal type and equal value comparsion?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.body
//returns [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

If i compare this way: `document.body == "[object HTMLBodyElement]"` returns true. But if i compare with `===` i think the type is not equal. If i try this way: `document.body === [HTMLBodyElement]` returns false. Or if this way: `document.body === HTMLBodyElement` also returns false. What is the value of `x` if i want this to return true: `document.body === x`

Comment: `let x = document.body`? Not sure what you’re trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Of course it doesn't return true with ===, you are comparing a type `object` with a type `string`. So yes, it will return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you compare object of html to a string ?

document.body is an object.

if you want to compare it you need to compare it either with similar object

```js
let body=document.body
console.log(document.body===body)
console.log(typeof document.body=="object");
console.log(document.body == "[object HTMLBodyElement]"&& typeof document.body==="object")
```